# Spring boot application restarts on its own when Elastic search is down

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, elasticsearch, spring-data

I have a spring boot application that is integrated with MySQL and Elastic Search. Most APIs connect directly with MySQL to fetch the data. Only 1 API fetch data from elastic search.

If Elastic Search goes down while the application is still running, the entire application tries to restart and fails since it is unable to connect with ES. When I checked the logs, I can see a lot of org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException error

> @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on Application: Invocation
> of init method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate
> [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]:
> Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
> org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.UncategorizedElasticsearchException:
> method [HEAD],

This causes the remaining APIs to be unavailable as well although they don't need Elastic Search to work. Is there a way to make sure the application stills runs fine even when the Elastic search is down? I did prefer to have only one API unavailable instead of the whole application going down

Comment: Please post the error on the restart case.

Comment: Hi Mohan....I have updated the post with the error I am seeing in logs

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: @TorbenPiJensen - I didn't find a solution yet. When I did some google I got to know that the spring boot actuator sends a heartbeat to the ES cluster to check if it's alive. Maybe when it finds out that ES is down, it restarts the whole application. We can turn off the actuator's ES health check by using the property management.health.elasticsearch.enabled=false        Personally, I don't think it's a good solution though. We will lose the ability to self-heal when ES goes down for only a few seconds.

Comment: I just realized that if you set ", createIndex = false" on the @Document annotations it won't connect to elastic search before you do anything on the repository. And to me it is fine that I have to create the index my self.

Comment: Thanks @TorbenPiJensen - Let me give that a try

Comment: Did it work adding the annotations?